# EU citizen traveling to the UK after Aug 2, 2021; vaccinated for COVID-19 in the US. Will I have to quarantine?

Tags: usa, uk, covid-19, eu-citizens

I am an EU citizen that has been vaccinated for COVID-19 in the US, and I will visit the UK on Aug 4, 2021, from an amber list country (https://www.gov.uk/guidance/red-amber-and-green-list-rules-for-entering-england#amber-list). I saw that the UK will drop the quarantine requirement for those that have been vaccinated in the EU or US *and* are arriving after 4am on Aug 2, 2021 from an amber list country.

Source:

https://www.gov.uk/government/news/uk-travel-update-government-waives-quarantine-for-arrivals-fully-vaccinated-from-europe-and-usa-while-also-confirming-international-cruise-restart.

However, it says in the link above that

> Those vaccinated in the US will also need to provide proof of US
> residency.

My question: Since I am *not* a US resident, what is going to happen in my case? Can I avoid quarantine? Does anyone know if there is a way to ask the UK authorities this question?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It would be better to contact your consulate in the UK, since they will be more likely to have a contact within the UK government that could clarify the situation. If you have returned to the EU, try to get a **EU Digital COVID Certificate** which may help. Otherwise, without knowing the reason why this condition has been added, you should assume it will be enforced.

Comment: You could always get an extra vaccine dose as a measure of last resort. J&J would be the quickest option if available locally.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.